# Alternating Sign Sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence

#### Introduction

The [sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_(mathematics)) of a number is either a `+`, or a `-` for every non-zero integer. Zero itself is signless (`+0` is the same as `-0`). In the following sequence, we are going to alternate between the **positive sign**, the **zero** and the **negative sign**. The sequence starts with `1`, so we write `1` with a positive sign, with zero (this one is weird, but we just multiply the number by 0) and the negative sign:

```
1, 0, -1
```

The next number is `2`, and we do the same thing again:

```
2, 0, -2
```

The sequence eventually is:

```
1, 0, -1, 2, 0, -2, 3, 0, -3, 4, 0, -4, 5, 0, -5, 6, 0, -6, 7, 0, -7, ...
```

Or a more readable form:

```
a(0) = 1
a(1) = 0
a(2) = -1
a(3) = 2
a(4) = 0
a(5) = -2
a(6) = 3
a(7) = 0
a(8) = -3
a(9) = 4
...
```

#### The Task

Given a non-negative integer *n*, output the *n*<sup>th</sup> term of the above sequence. You can choose if you use the **zero-indexed** or **one-indexed** version.

#### Test cases:

Zero-indexed:

```
a(0) = 1
a(11) = -4
a(76) = 0
a(134) = -45
a(296) = -99
```

Or if you prefer one-indexed:

```
a(1) = 1
a(12) = -4
a(77) = 0
a(135) = -45
a(297) = -99
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the smallest number of bytes wins!

Comment: Is it Ok if you start with `[0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1...`

Comment: @muddyfish no sorry, it has to start with `1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Jelly, 7 bytes

```
+6d3’PN
```

Zero-indexed.
[Test cases here.](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=KzZkM-KAmVBOCjAsMSwyLDMsNCw1w4figqw&input=&args=OQ)

Explanation:

```
+6      Add 6:     x+6
d3      Divmod:    [(x+6)/3, (x+6)%3]
’       Decrement: [(x+6)/3-1, (x+6)%3-1]
P       Product    ((x+6)/3-1) * ((x+6)%3-1)
```

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript ES6, 18 bytes

```javascript
n=>-~(n/3)*(1-n%3)
```

Turned out very similar to @LeakyNun's answer but I didn't see his until after I posted mine.

### Explanation and Ungolfed

`-~` is shorthand for `Math.ceil`, or rounding up:

```javascript
n =>               // input in var `n`
    Math.ceil(n/3) // Get every 3rd number 1,1,1,2,2,2, etc.
    *
    (1-n%3)        // 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, ...
```

```js
function f(n){n=i.value;o.value=-~(n/3)*(1-n%3);}
```

```html
Input: <input id=i oninput="f()"/><br /><br />
Output: <input id=o readable/>
```

Comment: (I hereby attest that he did not see my solution before he posted his solution)

Comment: `Math.ceil` and `-~` are different; `Math.ceil(1) == 1` whereas `-~1 == 2`

Comment: 1 byte shorter: `n=>~(n/3)*~-(n%3)`

Answer (score 6):

## MarioLANG, <s>93</s> 81 bytes

*one-indexed*

[**Try It Online**](http://mariolang.tryitonline.net/#code=OygtKSkrKC0KIj09PT09PT09PT09PTwKPjooIVs8OiFbPDopIVsKICE9Iz0iISM9IiE9Iz0KISAgPCAhLTwgIS0gPAojPT0iICM9IiAjPT0i&input=OTY)

```
;(-))+(-
"============<
>:(![<:![<:)![
 !=#="!#="!=#=
!  < !-< !- <
#==" #=" #=="
```

**Explanation :**

we begin by taking the imput

```
;
```

wich give us

```
          v
... 0 0 input 0 0 ...
```

we then decrement the left byte and increment the right byte with

```
;(-))+(
=======
```

we end up with

```
           v
... 0 -1 input +1 0 ...
```

we then set up the loop

```
;(-))+(-
"============<
>  ![< ![<  ![
   #=" #="  #=
!  < !-< !- <
#==" #=" #=="
```

the loop will go until the memory look like

```
         v 
... 0 -X 0 +X 0 ...
```

we then only need to output the result

```
;(-))+(-
"============<
>:(![<:![<:)![
 !=#="!#="!=#=
!  < !-< !- <
#==" #=" #=="
```

Comment: Nice! You seem to like MarioLang.

Comment: @EasterlyIrk The feeling doesn't seem mutual from MarioLang to EtherFrog, though: `;(` and `>:(`. Although, two times `[<:` could be considered slightly happy. ;P

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 24 bytes

```python
lambda n:(n/3+1)*(1-n%3)
```

### Full program:

```python
a=lambda n:(n/3+1)*(1-n%3)

print(a(0))   #   1
print(a(11))  #  -4
print(a(76))  #   0
print(a(134)) # -45
print(a(296)) # -99
```

Answer (score 4):

## MATL,  <s>15</s>  12 bytes

```
3/XkG3X\2-*_
```

This uses one based indexing.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=My9Ya0czWFwyLSpf&input=NA) or [verify test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=My9Ya0czWFwyLSpf&input=WzEgMiAzIDQgNSA2IDcgOCA5XQ)

Explanation:

```
    G          #Input
     3X\       #Modulus, except multiples of 3 give 3 instead of 0
        2-     #Subtract 2, giving -1, 0 or 1
3/Xk           #Ceiling of input divided by 3.
          *    #Multiply 
           _   #Negate
```

Comment: To take care of most of the issues something like `Q3/Xk-1:1G_)*` may work better. It can probably be modified ever further for 1-based indexing instead.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 27 bytes

```
f x=div(x+3)3*(1-mod(x+3)3)
```

Slightly more interesting 28 byte solution:

```
(((\i->[i,0,-i])=<<[1..])!!)
```

(Both are `0`-indexed)

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, <strike>28</strike> 25 Bytes

```
echo $[(1+$1/3)*(1-$1%3)]
```

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, tkx, didn't know this...

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
:t~y_vG)
```

The result is 1-based.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OnR-eV92Ryk&input=MTM1)

#### Explanation

This builds the 2D array

```
 1  2  3  4  5 ...
 0  0  0  0  0 ...
-1 -2 -3 -4 -5 ...
```

and then uses linear indexing to extract the desired term. Linear indexing means index down, then across (so in the above array the first entries in linear order are `1`, `0`, `-1`, `2`, `0`, ...)

```
:     % Vector [1 2 ... N], where N is implicit input
t~    % Duplicate and logical negate: vector of zeros
y_    % Duplicate array below the top and negate: vector [-1 -2 ... -N]
v     % Concatenate all stack contents vertically
G)    % Index with input. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5, 22 bytes

21 plus one for `-p`:

```
$_=(-$_,$_+2)[$_%3]/3
```

Uses 1-based indexing.

Explanation:

`-p` sets the variable `$_` equal to the input. The code then sets it equal to the `$_%3`th element, divided by 3, of the 0-based list `(-$_,$_+2)` (where `%` is modulo). Note that if `$_%3` is two, then there is no such element, and the subsequent division by 3 numifies the undefined to 0. `-p` then prints `$_`.

Answer (score 3):

### 05AB1E, 7 bytes

**Code:**

```
(3‰`<*(
```

**Explained:**

```
(           # negate input: 12 -> -12
 3‰         # divmod by 3: [-4, 0]
   `        # flatten array: 0, -4
    <       # decrease the mod-result by 1: -1, -4
     *      # multiply: 4
      (     # negate -4
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, <s>8</s> 7 bytes (old version)

```
3.DeRt*
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk:3434/?code=3.DeRt%2a&input=10)
 - Note that link probably won't last for long

```
3.D      - a,b = divmod(input, 3)
   e     - a = ~a -(a+1)
     t   - b -= 1
      *  - a = a*b
         - implicit output a
```

Newest version

```
3.DhRt*_
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=3.DhRt%2a_&input=10)

```
3.D      - a,b = divmod(input, 3)
   h     - a+=1
     t   - b-=1
      *  - a = a*b
       _ - a = -a
         - implicit output a
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the (old version)

Comment: Latest commit where the old code works [here](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE/commit/acf4cd6d123febecdf15e949509bed585545da14) (this is earlier today)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>26</s>  23 bytes

```perl6
{({|(++$,0,--$)}...*)[$_]}
{($_ div 3+1)*(1-$_%3)}
```

( The shorter one was translated from other answers )

### Explanation (of the first one):

```perl6
{ # bare block with implicit parameter ｢$_｣
  (

    # start of sequence generator

    { # bare block
      |(  # slip ( so that it flattens into the outer sequence )
        ++$, # incrementing anon state var =>  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
        0,   # 0                           =>  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        --$  # decrementing anon state var => -1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6
      )
    }
    ...  # repeat
    *    # indefinitely

    # end of sequence generator

  )[ $_ ] # get the nth one (zero based)
}
```

#### Test:

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6
use v6.c;
use Test;

# store it lexically
my &alt-seq-sign = {({|(++$,0,--$)}...*)[$_]}
my &short-one = {($_ div 3+1)*(1-$_%3)}

my @tests = (
    0 =>   1,
   11 =>  -4,
   76 =>   0,
  134 => -45,
  296 => -99,
  15..^30  => (6,0,-6,7,0,-7,8,0,-8,9,0,-9,10,0,-10)
);

plan @tests * 2 - 1;

for @tests {
  is alt-seq-sign( .key ), .value, 'alt-seq-sign  ' ~ .gist;

  next if .key ~~ Range; # doesn't support Range as an input
  is short-one(    .key ), .value, 'short-one     ' ~ .gist;
}
```

```
1..11
ok 1 - alt-seq-sign  0 => 1
ok 2 - short-one     0 => 1
ok 3 - alt-seq-sign  11 => -4
ok 4 - short-one     11 => -4
ok 5 - alt-seq-sign  76 => 0
ok 6 - short-one     76 => 0
ok 7 - alt-seq-sign  134 => -45
ok 8 - short-one     134 => -45
ok 9 - alt-seq-sign  296 => -99
ok 10 - short-one     296 => -99
ok 11 - alt-seq-sign  15..^30 => (6 0 -6 7 0 -7 8 0 -8 9 0 -9 10 0 -10)
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, <s>19</s> 15 bytes

```
>.@(%&3)*1-3|<:
```

Probably need to golf this further...

1-indexed.

#### Ungolfed:

```
>> choose_sign      =: 1-3|<:      NB. 1-((n-1)%3)
>> choose_magnitude =: >.@(%&3)    NB. ceil(n/3)
>> f                =: choose_sign * choose_magnitude
>> f 1 12 77
<< 1 _4 0
```

Where `>>` means input (STDIN) and `<<` means output (STDOUT).

Answer (score 2):

## J,  27 bytes

Whilst not the golfiest, I like it better, as it uses an agenda.

```
>.@(>:%3:)*1:`0:`_1:@.(3|])
```

Here is the tree decomposition of it:

```
         ┌─ >.      
  ┌─ @ ──┤    ┌─ >: 
  │      └────┼─ %  
  │           └─ 3: 
  ├─ *              
──┤           ┌─ 1: 
  │      ┌────┼─ 0: 
  │      │    └─ _1:
  └─ @. ─┤          
         │    ┌─ 3  
         └────┼─ |  
              └─ ]
```

This is very similar to Kenny's J answer, in that it chooses the magnitude and sign, but it's different in that I use an agenda to choose the sign.

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, 8 bytes

```
_3&\wq*_
```

This solution uses 1-based indexing into the sequence.

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=XzMmXHdxKl8&input=MQ)

[Modified version showing all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YF8zJlx3cSpfRFRd&input=MQoxMgo3NwoxMzUKMjk3)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab the input
_       % Negate the input
3&\     % Compute the modulus with 3. The second output is floor(N/3). Because we negated
        % the input, this is the equivalent of ceil(input/3)
w       % Flip the order of the outputs
q       % Subtract 1 from the result of mod to turn [0 1 2] into [-1 0 1]
*       % Take the product with ceil(input/3)
_       % Negate the result so that the sequence goes [N 0 -N] instead of [-N 0 N]
        % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
*h/Q3-1%Q3
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Ah%2FQ3-1%25Q3&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A11%0A76%0A134%0A296&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
*     : Multiply following two arguments
h/Q3  : 1 + Input/3
-1%Q3 : 1 - Input%3
```

Note: I've assumed the zero-indexed sequence.

Comment: [You would probably like to include this link.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=*h%2FQ3-1%25Q3&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A11%0A76%0A134%0A296&debug=0) Also, welcome to PPCG!

Comment: I got quite close to your solution... `*@(1ZtZ)%Q3h/Q3`

Comment: @FliiFe `(1ZtZ)` = `-L1 2`

Answer (score 2):

### Actually, 10 bytes

```
3@│\u)%1-*
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=M0DilIJcdSklMS0q&input=MTE)

Explanation:

```
3@│\u)%1-*
3@│         push 3, swap, duplicate entire stack ([n 3 n 3])
   \u)      floor division, increment, move to bottom ([n 3 n//3+1])
      %1-   mod, subtract from 1 ([1-n%3 n//3+1])
         *  multiply ([(1-n%3)*(n//3+1)])
```

Answer (score 2):

## Batch (Windows), 86 bytes

### Alternate.bat

```
SET /A r=%1%%3
SET /A d=(%1-r)/3+1
IF %r%==0 ECHO %d%
IF %r%==1 ECHO 0
IF %r%==2 ECHO -%d%
```

This program is run as `Alternate.bat n` where `n` is the number you wish to call the function on.

Answer (score 2):

## GeoGebra, 44 bytes

```
Element[Flatten[Sequence[{t,0,-t},t,1,n]],n]
```

where `n` is one-indexed.

Explanation:

```
Element[                      , n] # Return the nth element of the list                  .
 Flatten[                    ]     # Strip all the unnecessary braces from the list     /|\
  Sequence[{t,0,-t}, t, 1, n]      # Generate a list of lists of the form {t, 0, -t}     |
                             # This list will start with {1,0,-1} and end with {n,0,-n}  |
```

It is not necessary to generate all triplets through `{n, 0, -n}`, but it's shorter than writing `ceil(n/3)` or something to that effect.
Note that `n` must be defined to create this object (if it isn't defined at the time this is run, GeoGebra will prompt you to create a slider for `n`).

Comment: Hi and welcome to PPCG! Do you have a link I can test this (preferably online)?

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ, thanks! Here's a [link](https://www.geogebra.org/algebra) to an online applet thingamabob. The page looked blank for a little while, but then it showed up.

Comment: Oh cool. But how where do I put in the formula? >_> I tried pasting it into the blank, and it prompted to create a slider, but nothing else happened.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ: Over on the left-hand side, where it says "Input..." First, to initialise `n`, enter something like `n=297` (this will give you a slider that's configured nicely). Then paste the formula into the Input box, which should now be below the `n`. (Make sure to hit return ;) The formula should evaluate to the `n`th term of the sequence, and it should change when you move the slider.

Answer (score 2):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), <s>17</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes using Sok's idea of using `1-(n%3)` instead of `~(n%3-2)`.*

```
1?:#/)}_3%-{*!
```

The program terminates with an error (division by zero), but the error message goes to STDERR.

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=MT86Iy8pfV8zJS17KiE&input=Mjk2)

#### Explanation

The program is completely linear, although some code is executed in reverse at the end.

```
1     Turn top of stack into 1.
?:    Read input as integer and duplicate.
#     Push stack depth (3).
/)    Divide and increment.
}     Move over to auxiliary stack.
_3%   Take other copy modulo 3.
-     Subtract from 1. This turns 0, 1, 2 into 1, 0, -1, respectively.
{*    Move other value back onto main stack and multiply.
!     Output as integer.
```

The instruction pointer now hits a dead end and turns around, so it starts to execute the code from the end:

```
*     Multiply two (implicit) zeros.
{     Pull an (implicit) zero from the auxiliary to the main stack.
-     Subtract two (implicit) zeros from one another.
      Note that these were all effectively no-ops due to the stacks which are
      implicitly filled with zeros.
%     Attempt modulo, which terminates the program due to a division-by-zero error.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Erlang, 40 bytes

```
F=fun(N)->trunc((N/3+1)*(1-N rem 3))end.
```

Sadly Erlang has no '%' modulo operator and 'rem' requires the spaces, even before the 3.

Answer (score 2):

## [Hexagony](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexagony), 25 bytes

```
?'+}@/)${':/3$~{3'.%(/'*!
```

Or, in non-minified format:

```
    ? ' + }
   @ / ) $ {
  ' : / 3 $ ~
 { 3 ' . % ( /
  ' * ! . . .
   . . . . .
    . . . .
```

[Try  it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=PycrfUAvKSR7JzovMyR-ezMnLiUoLycqIQ&input=Mjk2)

My first foray into Hexagony, so I'm certain I've not done this anywhere near as efficiently as it could be done...

Calculates `-(n%3 - 1)` on one memory edge, `n/3 + 1` on an adjacent one, then multiplies them together.

Comment: Wow, very interesting to see this! :)

Answer (score 2):

## R, 28 bytes

```
-((n=scan())%%3-1)*(n%/%3+1)
```

Looks like this is a variation of most of the answers here.  Zero based.

```
   n=scan()                  # get input from STDIN
  (        )%%3-1            # mod by 3 and shift down (0,1,2) -> (-1,0,1)
-(               )           # negate result (1,0,-1), this handles the alternating signs
                  *(n%/%3+1) # integer division of n by 3, add 1, multiply by previous
```

The nice thing about it is that it handles multiple inputs

```
> -((n=scan())%%3-1)*(n%/%3+1)
1: 0 3 6 9 1 4 7 10 2 5 8 11
13: 
Read 12 items
 [1]  1  2  3  4  0  0  0  0 -1 -2 -3 -4
>
```

Originally I wanted to do the following, but couldn't trim off the extra bytes.

```
rbind(I<-1:(n=scan()),0,-I)[n]
```

Uses `rbind` to add 0's and negatives to a range of 1 to `n` then return the `n`'th term (one based).

```
# for n = 5
rbind(                    )    # bind rows 
            n=scan()           # get input from STDIN and assign to n
      I<-1:(        )          # build range 1 to n and assign to I
                     ,0        # add a row of zeros (expanded automatically)
                       ,-I     # add a row of negatives
                           [n] # return the n'th term
```

Answer (score 2):

### APL, 12 chars

```
-×/1-0 3⊤6+⎕
```

`0 3⊤` is APL's `divmod 3`.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 7, <strike>38</strike> <strike>37</strike> 36 bytes

My first golf, be gentle

```
int a(int i){return(1+i/3)*(1-i%3);}
```

[Try it here!](https://ideone.com/t52W7d) (test cases included)

Edit: I miscounted, and also golfed off one more character by replacing `(-i%3+1)` with `(1-i%3)`.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG! You can remove the space after `return`, and use a Java 8 lambda.

Comment: I should specify that this was Java 7.  I'll remove that space, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, 45 bytes

```
.+
11$&$*
(111)+(1)*
$#2$#1
T`d`+0-`^.
^0.+
0
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LisKMTEkJiQqCigxMTEpKygxKSoKJCMyJCMxClRgZGArMC1gXi4KXjAuKwow&input=MTI)

[Test suite.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShgLisKMTEkJiQqCigxMTEpKygxKSoKJCMyJCMxClRgZGArMC1gXi4KXjAuKwow&input=MQoxMgo3NwoxMzUKMjk3)

Takes input/output in base-ten. 1-indexed.

#### Unary input, base-ten output, 1-indexed: 40 bytes

```
$
11
(111)+(1)*
$#2$#1
T`d`+0-`^.
^0.+
0
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JAoxMQooMTExKSsoMSkqCiQjMiQjMQpUYGRgKzAtYF4uCl4wLisKMA&input=MTExMTExMTExMTEx)

[Test suite.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShgJAoxMQooMTExKSsoMSkqCiQjMiQjMQpUYGRgKzAtYF4uCl4wLisKMA&input=MQoxMTExMTExMTExMTEKMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTEKMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExCjExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMQ)

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/a(1+%1/3)*(1-%1%%3)
```

The `cmd/c` makes `set/a` echo the result of the calculation. Edit: Saved 1 byte by removing the unnecessary space.

Answer (score 1):

## GNU Coreutils, 27 Bytes

```
echo "(1+$1/3)*(1-$1%3)"|bc
```

Comment: I count 27 bytes.  But this is even shorter: `bc<<<"(1+$1/3)*(1-$1%3)"`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, I wrote exactly this answer before, but I am not sure if `<<<` is POSIX-ly correct, and I want to avoid Bash-ism here, as I have a plain Bash answer here, too.

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB / Octave, 27 bytes

```
@(n)ceil(n/3)*(mod(-n,3)-1)
```

This creates an anonymous function that can be called using `ans(n)`. This solution uses 1-based indexing.

[All test cases](http://ideone.com/WsepZL)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica 26 bytes

With 4 bytes saved thanks to Martin Ender.

```
⎡#/3⎤(-#~Mod~3-1)&
```

Uses the same approach as Suever.

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 23 bytes

With no mod cons...

```
@(n)(-[-1:1]'*[1:n])(n)
```

Uses 1-based indexing magic.

---

**Explanation**

Creates an anonymous function that will:

```
(-[-1:1]'*[1:n])(n)
  [-1:1]              % make a row vector [-1 0 1]
 -      '             % negate and take its transpose making a column vector
          [1:n]       % make a row vector [1..n], where n is the input
         *            % multiply with singleton expansion
               (n)    % use linear indexing to get the nth value
```

After the multiplication step we'll have a 3xn matrix like so (for n=12):

```
 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
 0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
-1   -2   -3   -4   -5   -6   -7   -8   -9  -10  -11  -12
```

Making `n` columns is overkill, but it's a convenient number that is guaranteed to be large enough. Linear indexing counts down each column from left to right, so the element at linear index `4` would be `2`.

All test cases on [ideone](http://ideone.com/LwePaM).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 22 bytes

```
r=n%3
o=(1-r)/3*(n-r+3)
```

`n` is the number you wish to call the function on. `o` is the output number.

Answer (score 1):

## dc, 10

```
?2+3~1r-*p
```

Uses 1-based indexing.

```
?              # Push input to stack
 2+            # Add 2
   3~          # divmod by 3
     1r-       # subtract remainder from 1
        *      # multiply by quotient
         p     # print
```

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 14 bytes

```
{⍵⌷∊{⍵0,-⍵}¨⍳⍵}
```

This is 1-indexed, i.e.:

```
     {⍵⌷∊{⍵0,-⍵}¨⍳⍵}¨1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 0 ¯1 2 0 ¯2 3 0
```

Explanation:

```
{⍵⌷                   select the ⍵th element
   ∊                  from all elements in
    {⍵0,-⍵}           the values ⍵, 0, and -⍵
           ¨⍳⍵}       for each number in 1..⍵
```

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 11 bytes

```
ri3+3md(W**
```

0-based input.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri3%2B3md(W**&input=296)

#### Explanation

```
ri   e# Read input and convert to integer N.
3+   e# Add 3.
3md  e# Divmod 3, putting N/3+1 and N%3 on the stack.
(W*  e# Decrement, multiply by -1, turning 0, 1, 2 into 1, 0, -1, respectively.
*    e# Multiply.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 16+3 = 19 bytes

```
:3%:1$-}-3,1+*n;
```

Needs the input to be present on the stack, so +3 bytes for the `-v` flag. [Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=OjMlOjEkLX0tMywxKypuOw&input=&args=LXYgMjk2)

The program outputs the **zero-indexed** sequence, using the formula:

`f(n) = ((n-(n%3))/3) * (1-(n%3))`

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 36 bytes

```
int c(int n){return(n/3+1)*(1-n%3);}
```

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/t35aTN)

```
class Main{

    static int c(int n){
        return (n / 3 + 1) * (1 - n % 3);
    }

    public static void main(String[] a){
        System.out.println(c(0));
        System.out.println(c(11));
        System.out.println(c(76));
        System.out.println(c(134));
        System.out.println(c(296));
    }
}
```

**Zero-indexed output:**

```
1
-4
0
-45
-99
```

Answer (score 1):

## Desmos, <s>125</s> 86 bytes

```
b=\operatorname{ceil}\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)
b\operatorname{mod}\left(-a,3\right)-b
a=1
```

Simple fix for `\operatorname{ceil}\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)`

125 bytes:

```
\operatorname{ceil}\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)\operatorname{mod}\left(-a,3\right)-\operatorname{ceil}\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)
a=1
```

This is as close as I could get to divmod.  Might be able to get rid of subtracting `-\operatorname{ceil}\left(\frac{a}{3}\right)` to shave some bytes off.

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 30 bytes

```
1..-.w>?^I3%?;,)O@...o-'.<u;;;
```

Try it [here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix).  You will need to replace the current code with the above and enter an input number.
This wraps onto a cube with an edge length of 3.  I'm hoping to reduce this a bit more, but at the moment it's not to bad.  It would be nice to have some of the planned features for the stack, but oh well.

```
      1 . .
      - . w
      > ? ^
I 3 % ? ; , ) O @ . . .
o - ' . < u ; ; ; . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

Explanation:

- `I 3 % ?` Take a number from input, push a literal 3, mod on TOS and do a check.  The `?` redirects right for negative and left for positive.  Pass through for zero
- For zero value `; , ) O @` Pop, integer divide TOS, increment TOS, output number and terminate
- For positive value `1 - > ?` Push literal 1, subtract TOS, change direction and check

  - For zero value `^ w O @` Redirect up, sidestep left (ends up on another face), output number (zero in this case) and terminate
  - For positive value `; < ' - o ; ; ; u , ) O @` pop, redirect, push character -, output character, pop, pop, pop, u-turn to left, integer divide TOS, increment TOS, output number and terminate

Comment: What happend to the other answer? :)

Comment: My apologies for the edit mess up, I thought I had lost the previous post

Comment: Oh, it's okay :)

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 34 bytes

```
n=>n%3==1?0:(n/3+1)*(n%3==0?1:-1);
```

To assign the lambda to a variable, write:

```
Func<int,int>f=n=>n%3==1?0:(n/3+1)*(n%3==0?1:-1);
```

With C# 6, you can also assign the lambda to a method:

```
int F(int n)=>n%3==1?0:(n/3+1)*(n%3==0?1:-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>30</s> 25 bytes

I tried to replicate the results of Leaky Nun's Python post for 10 minutes before realising it was for Python 2, not 3.

Zero-indexed:

```py
lambda n:(n//3+1)*(1-n%3)
```

### Full program:

```py
a = lambda n:(n//3+1)*(1-n%3)
print(a(0))   #   1
print(a(11))  #  -4
print(a(76))  #   0
print(a(134)) # -45
print(a(296)) # -99
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, @NoOneIsHere. Pleasure to be here!

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 19 bytes

Using lambda expressions.

```
i->(1+i/3)*(1-i%3);
```

[Try it here!](https://ideone.com/Rsyl7N)

Comment: [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##fc/PasMwDAbwc/0U36VgD5w0S9YRQvcGO/U4dlD@dKhznNC4hVHSV88UyI6ZLwLrJ33oTDeyXd/4c/09VY6GAe/EHne1YR@ay4mqBo7asqa7fKDr9VzYFKMChkCBq6UPwgET27eH5jg1Tw@reZuaYlIQ2l9LJ3SZuHVco5UgfWJPDsdwYf/18YnSSDTkHX@G0LRRdw1RL73gvKZI0nfGFEAcC0nUZk0lycxmZbN19br/U9j9syvNhImy2cu6es73i8pzOWBU4/QL "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Oasis](http://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 12 bytes (non-competing)

```
n3÷>n3÷y>n-*
```

[Try it online!](http://oasis.tryitonline.net/#code=bjPDtz5uM8O3eT5uLSo&input=&args=Mjk2)

Oasis is a language designed by [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan) which is specialized in sequences.

Currently, this language can do recursion and closed form.

This answer can only demonstrate closed form. For recursion, see for example [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91819/48934).

We use this formula: `a(n) = (n/3+1)*((n/3*3)+1-n)` which is modified from [the formula used in my Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80859/48934), since there is no modulo at the moment.

```
n3÷>n3÷y>n-*

n             push n (input)
 3÷           integer-division by 3
   >          +1
    n         push n (input)
     3÷       integer-division by 3
       y      *3
        >     +1
         n    push n (input)
          -   subtract the top of stack from the second top of stack
           *  multiply the top of stack to the second top of stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 64 bytes

Although Leaky Nun has already posted a [much shorter, brilliant Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80859/60919), I decided to see whether this could be done recursively, calculating each new term from the last two. The result was interesting:

```python
f=lambda n,a=1,b=0:(n<1)*`a`or f(n-1,b,[[0,-a][b==0],1-b][a==0])
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsMgEEDRdXsKlzNlBM1SOicRISOJjZCOQbLJ6W26@zz@cZ1b02mMwrt88yJGSdhTZhdA3x5fs8ytmwJqb6UYHVlJMTO7RN7mFOWfOMp9VVPVdNHPCpPD8HwcveoJBSri@AE)**

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 50 bytes

```
function a(n)print((math.floor(n/3)+1)*(1-n%3))end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcnLCoQwDEDRvV@RjZAonTHWB/2cMKMoaCqlfn99dHcPdzslpfnUX1y9gqDSEVaNiLvE5TNv3gfUr6WaqUI2WlqiSf9JsCEAMAa4EGSmt013YxwymmfYjvLob7VuyHIuXQ)

Answer (score 0):

**VBA Excel , 46 bytes**

using immediate window and `Range A1` as input

```
a=[A1]:b=a Mod 3:?IIf(b=0,-a/3,IIf(b=1,a/3,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, <s>73</s> 43 bytes

```
(lambda(n)(*(1+(floor n 3))(- 1(mod n 3))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74r1FQlJlXoqDxXyMnMTcpJVEjT1NDS8NQWyMtJz@/SCFPwVhTU0NXwVAjNz8FwtPU/G8JxAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 52 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 6.5 bytes

```
Þn2ẇ0Zfi
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJBPSIsIiIsIsOebjLhuocwWmZpIiwiIiwiMVxuMTJcbjc3XG4xMzVcbjI5NyJd)

Bitstring:

```
0010101100100111101111111101010011100010011001000000
```

Silly vyxal (1 indexed)